# Разложить вложенную агрегацию в Opensearch

Tags: запрос, group-by, elasticsearch

Есть запрос с вложенной агрегацией:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "from": "now-20m",
                            "to": null
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "composite_agg": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "composite.keyword"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "interface": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "interface.keyword"
                    },
                    "aggregations": {
                        "out_error": {
                            "date_histogram": {
                                "field": "@timestamp",
                                "interval": "10m"
                            },
                            "aggregations": {
                                "errors": {
                                    "avg": {
                                        "field": "interface.out_error"
                                    }
                                },
                                "thirtieth_difference": {
                                    "serial_diff": {
                                        "buckets_path": [
                                            "errors"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Результат запроса:

```
{
    "took": 23,
    "timed_out": false,
    "aggregations": {
        "composite_agg": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "doc_count": 3540,
                    "interface": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 320,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "doc_count": 320,
                                "key": "someinterface1",
                                "out_error": {
                                    "buckets": [
                                        {
                                            "key_as_string": "2023-04-09T11:00:00.000Z",
                                            "doc_count": 16,
                                            "key": 1681038000000,
                                            "errors": {
                                                "value": 0
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key_as_string": "2023-04-09T11:10:00.000Z",
                                            "doc_count": 160,
                                            "thirtieth_difference": {
                                                "value": 0
                                            },
                                            "key": 1681038600000,
                                            "errors": {
                                                "value": 0
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key_as_string": "2023-04-09T11:20:00.000Z",
                                            "doc_count": 144,
                                            "thirtieth_difference": {
                                                "value": 0
                                            },
                                            "key": 1681039200000,
                                            "errors": {
                                                "value": 0
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "key": "somecomposite1"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Есть ли параметр, который можно указать в запросе при агрегации, чтобы получить данные в разложенном виде, и, из "самой" вложенной агрегации доставать последний элемент в поле `out_error`? Примерно в таком виде:

```
{
    "took": 23,
    "timed_out": false,
    "aggregations": {
        "composite_agg": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "doc_count": 320,
                    "key": "someinterface1",
                    "composite_agg.key": "somecomposite1",
                    "composite_agg.doc_count": 3540,
                    "out_error": {
                        "thirtieth_difference": {
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "doc_count": 123,
                    "key": "someinterfaceN",
                    "composite_agg.key": "somecompositeN",
                    "composite_agg.doc_count": 3540,
                    "out_error": {
                        "thirtieth_difference": {
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```